# SQL frequency count

Tags: sql-server, count, frequency

I have a table in SSMS:

```
Id  Date    Value
111 1/1/18  x
111 1/2/18  x
111 1/3/18  y
111 1/4/18  y
111 1/5/18  x
111 1/6/18  x
222 1/3/18  z
222 1/6/18  y
222 1/8/18  y
```

I want to count for the frequency of latest value . So the output will be:

```
Id  Value  Days
111 x      2   *(for 1/5/18 & 1/6/18)*
222 y      3   *(for 1/6/18 & 1/8/18; Here I assume 1/7/18 is a weekend or holiday.  Even though my table skips the weekend, we still want to count days for the weekend)*
```

How would this be done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag` to get the previous row's value and then a running sum to assign groups. Thereafter count the number in the first group.

```
select id,val,datediff(day,min(date),max(date))+1 as days
from (select t.*,sum(case when val=prev_val then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by date desc) as grp
      from (select t.*,lag(val) over(partition by id order by date desc) as prev_val
            from tbl t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp=1
group by id,val
```

Comment: When I ran this, it only has "2" for (222,y) instead of 3 expected by OP

Comment: From example: `3   *(for 1/6/18 & 1/8/18; Here I assume 1/7/18 is a weekend or holiday.`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala thank you :) Btw, if I remove "where grp = 1" will that should all the entries instead of keep last?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Value = 
(
    SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE Id = MAX(Id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want this

```
select Id, count(Date) as "Days", Value from SSMS
group by ID, Value
```

correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I tried this but this won't work since the weekend is skipped, and we want the days count for the lastest value only

Comment: you do not have weekend as entry in ur table

Comment: I agree, the table was set up that way.

Answer (score 1):

This answer should account for the weekends and holiday assumptions you have made (with another test case).

```
SELECT
    T.Id, T.val, DATEDIFF(DD, COALESCE(T.MaxSwitch, T.MinMatch, T.MaxDate), T.MaxDate) + 1 AS [Days]
FROM (
    SELECT
        T.Id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN T.LastValue IS NULL THEN T.val ELSE '' END) AS [val],
        MAX(T.Date) AS [MaxDate],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.val <> t.LastValue THEN T.RunningDate ELSE NULL END) AS [MaxSwitch],
        MIN(CASE WHEN t.val = t.LastValue THEN T.[Date] ELSE NULL END) AS [MinMatch]
    FROM (SELECT *, LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS LastValue,
        LAG([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RunningDate FROM @T) T
    GROUP BY 
        T.Id
    ) T
```

This approach uses `LAG` to track previous value and date so that it can determine (1) the last value to get running match, (2) the latest date when value switched to most recent value, and (3) the earliest date with value matching final date. It then calculates the date difference to account for skipping days in table from priority of (A) latest date value switched to recent value, (B) or if no switch occurred, then earliest date with value matching final date.

For the sample data below:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    Id INT, [Date] DATE, val VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT @T VALUES
    ('111', '1/1/18', 'x'),
    ('111', '1/2/18', 'x'),
    ('111', '1/3/18', 'y'),
    ('111', '1/4/18', 'y'),
    ('111', '1/5/18', 'x'),
    ('111', '1/6/18', 'x'),
    ('222', '1/2/18', 'y'),
    ('222', '1/3/18', 'z'),
    ('222', '1/6/18', 'y'),
    ('222', '1/8/18', 'y'),
    ('333', '1/9/18', 'a')
```

The following output is given:

```
Id          val        Days
----------- ---------- -----------
111         x          2 (from OP example)
222         y          3 (from OP example)
333         a          1 (case of single value)
```